# Using ENSIME with an established Scala project using Maven

Tags: scala, maven, emacs, ensime

I am looking into setting up a development environment using emacs/ENSIME, hacking on [this project](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam/). The project uses Maven, though, with poms at the top level as well as within the three component subprojects (format, cli, core).

I am unable to figure out what I need to do with my .ensime configuration in order to get up and running (as the default configuration clearly doesn't cut it, nor can I get any of the various ensime-maven-cfg scripts I've found to work).

The most recent information I've found regarding Maven + ENSIME is from a year ago, [here](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-src/issues/301). The provided script does not work.

There must be someone who uses Maven and ENSIME successfully… I hope. How should I go about setting up my ENSIME configuration?

EDIT: I got much of it working just by setting :source-roots list in the .ensime config file. Adding the deps (via a [hacked together Python script](https://gist.github.com/ihodes/f5bf96daa8a6dfdff9fc) similar to the one linked above) doesn't seem to help with building, BUT I do have the Scala REPL now loading all of my deps properly. The semantics highligher & some other things still aren't working very well, but I can jump to definitions and use the type inspector.

All in all, it's much closer to working completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [written a script](https://gist.github.com/ihodes/11505022) that solves this problem; it's a bit hacky, and could be made to generate a smaller ensime config, but it suits my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I've added some commits to the ensime-maven-plugin here: https://github.com/parsnips/ensime-maven-plugin

Bringing that project back from the dead.